# adding matices with different shape python

Tags: python, numpy

I have 2 arrays with different dimensions. Let's fill them up with zeros using the numpy library:

```
A = np.zeros((24, 24, 24, 24))
B = np.zeros((24, 84, 24, 24))
```

I want to add these two arrays `A + B` to obtain a new matrix with dimensions:

```
C = [ 24, 108, 24, 24]
```

I thought of using bradcasting and the method add:

```
C = np.add(A, B)
```

but it does not work.

Do you have any idea how to solve this problem?

Comment: How do you imagine this working?  Addition is an element-by-element operation.  If the elements don't match up one-to-one, what exactly do you want NumPy to do instead?

Comment: I think you want `np.concatenate((A, B), axis=1)` (http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.concatenate.html).

Answer (score 1):

If by add you mean append, try: `np.append(a, b, axis = 1)`.

`assert np.append(a, b, axis = 1).shape == (24, 108, 24, 24)`.